# Angular mat-drawer-container cdkScrollable Unsubscription issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

`<mat-sidenav-content cdkScrollable>` and

constructor(public scroll: ScrollDispatcher) {

```
this.scrollingSubscription = this.scroll
      .scrolled()
      .subscribe((data: CdkScrollable) => {
        this.onWindowScroll(data);
      });
```

}

how to unsubscribe because its will active in other components

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.scrollingSubscription = this.scroll.scrolled().subscribe();
```

And then where you need it the following code

```js
this.scrollingSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Probably in component `ngOnDestroy(){}` method.

Comment: O sorry it is the subscription you need to unsubscribe, not the observable. I'll change the anwser.